# How to stop a windows service after appveyor deployment

Tags: powershell, asp.net-web-api, deployment, windows-services, appveyor

I want to stop the windows service after the appveyor deployment, only for
qa environment.

I have used the following lines in deploy.ps1 file.

```html
function SetService{
    Write-Host "Stopping service - $env:environment_name"
    if($env:environment_name -eq "QA")
    {
        Write-Host "$env:service_name"
        $serviceStatus = (Get-Service $env:service_name).Status
        Write-Host "$serviceStatus"
        Set-Service $env:service_name -StartupType Manual

            If (-Not ($serviceStatus -Eq 'Stopped')) {
            Write-Host "Stopping service $service..."
            Stop-Service $env:service_name
            }
    }
}
```

But, this is not working as expected, after the deployment it gets started automatically

[image]

How to stop the service after appveyor deployment?

Comment: In which step are you placing this script?

Comment: function Run{
  SetService
}

Comment: Do you try to use **Finalize** step?

Comment: inside .ps1 file? could you please share any sample for Finalize

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no way to test this in Veyor, but the documentation says that you can do this: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/

Comment: Use `do_not_start` setting: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/#deploying-artifact-package-as-a-windows-service